# unit testing using mock

Tags: c#, json, unit-testing

I'm trying to conduct unit test on my app.
This is my test:

```
class CustomerControllerTest
{
    [Test]
    public void GetAuctionsByJson_works()
    {
        // Arrange
        Mock<IAuctionRespository> mockAuction = new Mock<IAuctionRespository>();
        mockAuction.Setup(m => m.Auctions).Returns(new Auction[]
            {
                new Auction { a_id=1, auctionname="computer", deadLine=DateTime.Today},
                new Auction { a_id=2, auctionname="keyboard", deadLine=DateTime.Today},
                new Auction { a_id=3, auctionname="mouse", deadLine=DateTime.Today}
            }.AsQueryable());
        CustomerController controller = new CustomerController(mockAuction.Object);
        var actual = controller.GetAuctionsByJson() as JsonResult;
        //parse result
        List<Auction> result = actual.Data as List<Auction>; //null
        Assert.AreEqual(3, result.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result[0].a_id);
        Assert.AreEqual("computer", result[0].auctionname);
        Assert.AreEqual(DateTime.Today, result[0].deadLine);

    }
}
```

var actual has values (as seen in image)
[actual val](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJRKo.png)
but i get that var result is null
[result val](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fj4V.png)
why?
how can i get actual values in a list?
Thank

Comment: I guess there are two possible answers. 1. actual.Data is nof of type List<Auction> (the keyword as dosnt throw an exception in this case) 2. actual.Data is some kind of json object you need to deserialize first, you cant just cast it (this is the problem I would say)

Comment: Thank! The failure was due to lack of deserializion. I've done what you said and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andre! My solution was to add this lines:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Auction> result = serializer.Deserialize<List<Auction>>(serializer.Serialize(actual.Data));
```